# Include external folder in source control

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

My main software application folder is here:

> D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist

And it has sourec control using **TortoiseGit**. But I now have an additional folder here:

> C:\Users\ajtru\Documents\HelpNDoc\Templates\html\MSA HTML Template

It has to remain there because it is required by HelpNDoc in this location. Well, it does allow you to set a different location by default:

https://www.helpndoc.com/news/2014-06-03-advanced-keyword-management-and-custom-template-path-helpndoc-44

But that is not what I want to do as each of my programs will have their own templates.

So, what is the simplest way using TortoiseGit to include this external folder as part of the source control withotu constantly copying the folder? Can it be done?

Comment: You could set up a junction inside your working tree which points to the real folder.

Comment: @MrTux where can I learn about these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a junction inside your working tree which points to the real folder.

E.g. run as Administrator:

```
mklink /j D:\My Programs\2017\MeetSchedAssist\fromhere C:\Users\ajtru\Documents\HelpNDoc\Templates\html\MSA HTML Template\tohere
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/FileIO/hard-links-and-junctions